# How to use json data for Flot in DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatable, flot

I am trying to draw a barchart and show the data for that chart in a table below. For this I am using flot and datatables. What I want to do is use the json output in both.

This is what I have:

```
        $.ajax({ 
            type: "POST",
            url: '/index.php',
            dataType: 'json',
            success: function(r) {

                $.plot($("#placeholder"), [r], {
                    series: {
                        bars: {
                            show: true
                        }
                    }
                });


                $('#example').dataTable( {
                    "ajax": r
                } );

            },
            error: function(err) {

                alert("oops");
                return false;

            }

        });
```

The chart draws fine but datatables gives the following error:

```
DataTables warning: table id=example - Invalid JSON response. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/1
```

However, I have checked the json and it is valid and flot uses it fine. Json is:

```
{"data":[[0,1267],[1,1485],[2,1516],[3,1418],[4,1308],[5,1307],[6,1392]]}
```

This leads me to conclude that either the json format is incorrect for datatables or the jQuery is wrong. Can anyone guide me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('#example').dataTable( {
                    data: r.data
                } );
```